# Could not find or load main class while running a jar?

Tags: java, runtime-error

I am having a multi-module project structure, when I am building a jar from a module, its getting build but when I try to run that jar using:

```
java -jar <path to  that jar>.jar
```

It gives this eror:

```
Could not find or load main class <packageName.ClassNameWhereMyMainMethodIS>.java
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It's a runnable jar?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a runnable jar or use

```
java -cp <path to  that jar>.jar full.package.name.ClassName
```

when you don't define a manifest which indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry point.

Comment: Hi, after providing the class name I am still getting the same error?

Comment: Is this class have a method with signature public static void main(String[] args)?

Comment: Yes, it has one !! 

Comment: See oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run using:

```
java -cp TestApp.jar com.test.HelloWorld
```

-cp adds that jar to your classpath